# How to integrate BIRT report with php using wamp server?

Tags: java, php, tomcat, birt

I am trying to integrate BIRT report with php. I have followed the tutorial from http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363642/Intergrating-BIRT-with-PHP .I have used birt-rcp-report-designer-4_3_1 to design a sample report and was able to view the report using birt report viewer from tomcat `http://localhost:8080/Birt-Viewer/frameset?__report=new_report_1.rptdesign` .But I am unable to access the javabridge in tomcat as `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge` , it is showing 404 error. If I use php code

```
<?php 
require_once("http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");

echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();
?>
```

then also it is showing 404 error. Also after unzipping the JavaBridge.war in the tomcat there is no folder named  "java" inside JavaBridge. Probably it is because of that it is showing 404 error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute or relative path to your php java bridge file i.e (java.inc). In my case also that was showing problem from http path.

Comment: If I double click on the JavaBridge,jar file it shows a pop-up with "start a listener on port 8081?". And after that if I go to url http://localhost:8081 and place the php files in the same location. Then it is working. When I try to render a BIRT report then it shows "Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: ReferenceClass failed: new org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine"